# Android. Launch app from Dialer

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-dialer

This is what I have so far but nothing happens when I input this combination in dialer

```
public class DialReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.content.Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER );

        if(phoneNumber.equals("*#588637#")) { 
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context , Activity.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }

    }

}
}
```

and in androidmanifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.DialReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":background"
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with these small changes..

```
String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras.getString("Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER");

             if(phoneNumber.equals("*#588637#")) { 
             //do your stuff
             }
```

And do not forget to add this line in your Manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Also you may find these helpful..

- http://android.programmerguru.com/simple-dialer-application/
- http://tikuflower.blogspot.com/2011/12/android.html

Comment: android.intent doesnt exists

Comment: Not String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras.getString("Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER"); u must change to: String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

Answer (score 2):

Is the receiver getting the broadcast at all? If not, maybe you forgot to include the [PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) permission.

Comment: It doesnt get broadcast at all, i added permission but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

Add to this in manifest,
here host is 12456, so your secret code is `*#*#123456#*#*` (dial-in dialped)

```
<receiver android:name=".Dialer"> //here is your broadcast receiver class
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
            <data android:scheme="android_secret_code"
                  android:host="123456"
            />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

here is your Broadcast Receiver class :

```
 class Dialer : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
         // Declare Here your launcher activity in Intent
        var  i : Intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)  
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context!!.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ridoy's 2nd link,

> http://tikuflower.blogspot.com/2011/12/android.html

It should be

```
String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
```

rather than

```
String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras.getString("Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER");
```

That change works for me at least...