# Android get dialer package name

Tags: android, android-dialer

I need to get package name of an app which post notification about a missed call. As far as I understand it makes dialer app of a device. Can I get package name of dialer app on the device, I need it from API 19?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter all dialer applications using [`Intent.ACTION_DIAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) action and [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)). Where it will return list of applications which can dial phone. Read more at [Android: How to show a list of dialer app installed on my device instead of directly calling default dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044423/android-how-to-show-a-list-of-dialer-app-installed-on-my-device-instead-of-dire)

---

You can use below code, as it is

```
public List<String> getPackagesOfDialerApps(Context context){

    List<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<>();

    // Declare action which target application listen to initiate phone call
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    // Query for all those applications
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    // Read package name of all those applications
    for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos){
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
        packageNames.add(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
    }

    return packageNames;
}
```

Comment: how to get default dialer app

Answer (score -2):

To get an app's package (and activity name) you can use `adb` command.

Launch the app and then:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
```

From the output:

```
mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{
  e224f9d token=Token{
    d8b2e74 ActivityRecord{
      1d97647 u0 com.android.dialer/.app.DialtactsActivity t1078
    }
  }
}
```

You can say the app's package is `com.android.dialer` and activity name is `.app.DialtactsActivity`